# Undefined index: websites in ..module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, magento2.2.6

After trying to update from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6 I ran into an error message that it could not write to one of my files and thus needing to do a rollback on some of my backups. For some reason, I cannot complete the rollbacks (that's a separate issue I'm trying to investigate). When I navigate to my website I get "An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details."

Going to my exception.logs and opening it, I see the following error

> Notice: Undefined index: websites in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php on line 220 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index: websites in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php on line 220 at /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []

Now, heading to System.php line 220, this is the function:

```
private function cacheData(array $data)

{

    $this->cache->save(

        $this->serializer->serialize($data),

        $this->configType,

        [self::CACHE_TAG]

    );

    $this->cache->save(

        $this->serializer->serialize($data['default']),

        $this->configType . '_default',

        [self::CACHE_TAG]

    );

    $scopes = [];

    foreach (['websites', 'stores'] as $curScopeType) { ***This would be the 'Websites' in question.***

        foreach ($data[$curScopeType] as $curScopeId => $curScopeData) {

            $scopes[$curScopeType][$curScopeId] = 1;

            $this->cache->save(

                $this->serializer->serialize($curScopeData),

                $this->configType . '_' . $curScopeType . '_' . $curScopeId,

                [self::CACHE_TAG]

            );

        }

    }

    $this->cache->save(

        $this->serializer->serialize($scopes),

        $this->configType . "_scopes",

        [self::CACHE_TAG]

    );

}
```

Any help would be awesome! Thank you :)